# webOS controllers and assistant

Tags: webos, palm-pre

I've started tinkering with webOS and it's pretty cool. Out of all the major smartphone platforms I have to say that webOS is the easiest to work with. Currently I'm just trying to get an intuitive sense for the framework and I'm just tinkering with basic stuff like event handling, pushing and popping scenes, etc. This has gotten me far but I'm getting to the point where my applications need a little more modularity since they no longer logically fit on a single stage with multiple scenes. I would like to know how do I go about writing my own assistants and controllers and using them in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Eclipse with the plug in installed?

Even if not, just copy a basic controller and change around the class names everywhere you see it.

Say HomeController to PreferencesController

Add that preferencescontroller.js to your sources.json file and add a folder in the views called preferences with a file in there preferences_scene.html (I believe).

Since the current framework is MVC, you may also want to think about creating javascript models that would house your validation and even helper files that could be global or view specific.  None of this is truly enforced except through your own doing though.

Also, beyond that, in 5 days HP will have a conference that shows off their new devices and possibly even their new modular framework titled Enyo, so that may be more what you are hoping for.